# Trying to use inbuilt shell command "update" to flash custom firmware to router and it asks for devname

Tags: linux, router

I'm a newbie to linux and embedded systems and I've been trying to flash my router with custom firmware for a while now. I managed to find a matching .bin file but the included update command needs a "dev" to flash to.
I have included the responses below. please help me out if you know how to. Thanks.
P.S. I entered mtd16 and it says "flash_earse: Could not get MTD device info" entered the full response below.

```
~ # update upgrade.bin                                                              
compile at 17:42:38                                                             
useage: update filename devname

~ # cat /proc/mtd                                                                   
dev:    size   erasesize  name                                                  
mtd0: 00080000 00020000 "zloader"                                               
mtd1: 00100000 00020000 "uboot"                                                 
mtd2: 00080000 00020000 "cpurpm"                                                
mtd3: 00100000 00020000 "uboot-mirr"                                            
mtd4: 00100000 00020000 "nvfac"                                                 
mtd5: 00200000 00020000 "nvro"                                                  
mtd6: 00300000 00020000 "nvrw"                                                  
mtd7: 00100000 00020000 "fotaflag"                                              
mtd8: 00680000 00020000 "cpuphy"                                                
mtd9: 00080000 00020000 "sms"                                                   
mtd10: 00800000 00020000 "cpups"                                                
mtd11: 00500000 00020000 "cpuap"                                                
mtd12: 00200000 00020000 "cpfs"                                                 
mtd13: 00100000 00020000 "recovery"                                             
mtd14: 00100000 00020000 "recovery-kernel"                                      
mtd15: 00100000 00020000 "cdrom"                                                
mtd16: 04300000 00020000 "userdata"                                             
mtd17: 01200000 00020000 "fotaupdate"                                           
mtd18: 00100000 00020000 "yaffs"                                                
mtd19: 00400000 00020000 "securefs"    

~ # df -h                                                                           
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on              
ubi0:rootfs              57.9M     24.4M     33.5M  42% /                       
mdev                     24.3M         0     24.3M   0% /dev                    
tmpfs                    24.3M         0     24.3M   0% /dev/shm                
ubi1_0                    1.2M    100.0K      1.1M   8% /securefs               
mtd:yaffs                 1.0M    436.0K    588.0K  43% /yaffs                  
ubi0:rootfs              57.9M     24.4M     33.5M  42% /mnt/tmp                
    
~ # update upgrade.bin mtd16                                                    
compile at 17:42:38                                                             
flash_earse: Could not get MTD device info
```

Comment: does your custom firmware of choice have installation instructions? this is one of the few things where "just try things" can result in permanent brickage

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. No it didn’t come with any instructions. I was hoping to flash it using the command itself but it was unsuccessful. The hardware matches exactly in both old and new firmwares, so I was hoping maybe I can desolder and flash the Nand chip itself with the bin file ? What do you think about it ? Thanks again